# Remove 1 Light/Switch to Operate on It's Own

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture, light

I have 7 lights in my kitchen going into my butler's pantry. There are five light switches that controls the lights. 1 switch in the butler's pantry, 3 switches in the kitchen and 1 switch outside of the kitchen. I would like the light in the butler's pantry to be controlled on it's own with one switch and leave the others to control the lights in the kitchen. How do I change the wiring there to do so?

The first picture is of the light switch in the Butlers Pantry. It has one red wire at the top right and two black wires at the bottom left.

[image: Butler's Pantry Switch]

The next pictures are of the other light switches around the kitchen that operate the lights. The first switch pictured has two red wires at the top, two black wires at the bottom. The second switch pictured has one red wire at the top right and one black wire at the top left. Then one red wire at the bottom left and one black wire at the bottom right. The third switch has two black wires at the top and two black wires at the bottom.

[image: Kitchen Switch]
[image: Kitchen Switch]
[image: Kitchen Switch]

Then there is this switch that is right outside of the kitchen that also controls all 7 lights. It has one red wire at the bottom left, one black wire at the bottom right and one black wire at the top.

[image: Outside of Kitchen Switch]

I appreciate any help and assistance that you geniuses here can provide! Thanks in advance!

Inside of boxes

[image: Inside of box]

[image: Inside of box]

[image: Inside of box]

Comment: Can you post photos that look into the backs of all switch boxes involved please?

Comment: For Sure @ThreePhaseEel

Comment: It won't let me post the last two photos.

Comment: Position of the wires on the switches doesn't mean a thing.  The manufacturers of 3/4 way switches move them around every week!  You have to go by screw colors.

Comment: @I_AmVirgo -- is it saying you have too many photos in your question already?

Comment: Yes, haha @ThreePhaseEel. Probably because I am a new member here.

Comment: @I_AmVirgo post the extra photos to [imgur](https://imgur.com) then post a link to them in a comment here; that way, one of us can edit them in

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel https://imgur.com/a/k5RYDGm

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel any ideas?

Comment: @I_AmVirgo -- which box is which in the inside-the-box-photos?